# JavaScript: filter() Method Returning Back Original Array and Not Filtering

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, methods, filter

I have the following code below using the filter() array function.

```js
arr = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44]

function test(arr) {
  return arr.filter((element) => {
    return element >= 10
  });
}

console.log(test(arr))
```

My code is returning the original array ([ 12, 5, 8, 130, 44 ]) and not filtering at all.  What am I doing wrong?

Note: I want to use the filter() method for this.

Comment: Your code seems to work, something else must be the problem.

Comment: It's running correctly for me.

Comment: Works as designed. You can also do just `arr.filter(element => element >= 10);` no need for the return in this case etc.

Comment: The code you provided does not return the original array.

Answer (score 1):

You code is missing a few things, but you are on the right track. `Array.filter` doesn't change the original array. Set a variable,`var filter`, and set it equal to the function test. Then `console.log(filter(arr))`

Answer (score 1):

Filter returns a new array, so depending on how you are using your function, you most likely are looking at the original array, which you cannot do, you need to look at the filtered results.

```js
let arr = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44]

function test(arr) {
  return arr.filter((element) => {
    return element >= 10
  });
}

// The filtered results
console.log('The filtered array', test(arr))

// The original array
console.log('The original array', arr)
```

To modify the array in place you can use a while loop, and then splice the elements like this which will modify the array in place.

```js
let arr = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44]

// Get the initial length of the array
let i = arr.length

// Loop backwards over the array as not to skip values when they get removed
while(--i) {
  if(arr[i] > 10) continue
  arr.splice(i, 1)
}

console.log(arr)
```

Instead of a while, you could also just assign the value back to the original array overwriting is original value.

```js
let arr = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44]

function test(arr) {
  return arr.filter((element) => {
    return element >= 10
  });
}

// Assign the result back to arr
arr = test(arr)

// The new value of arr
console.log(arr)
```